# FastText converts Hebrew texts to unreadable encoding - any way to convert back?

Tags: python, character-encoding, fasttext

**NOTE:**
Have since found that the .txt file itself is already encoded in an unreadable format...is there any way to read the .txt file in a readable format?

b'' b'\xd7\xa7\xd7\x90&\xd7\xa0\xd7\xa6\xd7\x9c\xd7\xa8\xd7\x99\xd7\xaa \xd7\x92\xd7\xa8\xd7\x9e\xd7\xa0\xd7\x99\xd7\x94 \xd7\x90\xd7\xa0\xd7\x92\xd7\x9c\xd7\x94 \xd7\x9e\xd7\xa8\xd7\xa7\xd7\x9c \xd7\x90\xd7\x9e\xd7\xa8 \xd7\x90\xd7\xaa\xd7\x9e\xd7\xa9\xd7\x95\xd7\xaa \xd7\x9e\xd7\xa4\xd7\x9c\xd7\x92\xd7\x94 \xd7\xa9\xd7\x99&\xd7\x9c\xd7\x98\xd7\x95\xd7\x9f \xd7\x93\xd7\xa6\xd7\x9e\xd7\x91\xd7\xa8'

I'm trying to use FastText to create word embeddings for a Hebrew language text. It looks like FastText automatically converts the texts into a different (unreadable) character encoding. Does anyone know why this occurs and how the conversion can be cancelled?

I'm using Python 3.5 on a Windows computer. Have tried reading the vectorized words as 'UTF-8' encoding, but it still appeared in an unreadable format.

```
model = fasttext.cbow('your_file.txt', 'model')
model.words # list of words in dictionary
```

Here's how the vectors came out:

```
{'': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3f6cc208>,
 '8\\xd7\\x95\\xd7\\xa0\\xd7\\x99\\xd7\\x94': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3b2fbda0>,
 '2.199': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3aadf470>,
 '42381': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3b348160>,
 '7648': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3b0b7208>,
 '1.9841': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3afd8080>,
 '7\\x91\\xd7\\x90"\\xd7\\x90': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3b313e80>,
 "xa0\\xd7\\x92'\\xd7\\x99&\\xd7\\x9e\\xd7\\x99\\xd7\\x9f": <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3ab7b7f0>,
 '9e\\xd7\\x90\\xd7\\x9c': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3ad39748>,
 "a4\\xd7\\x99'": <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3a8e9b38>,
 '\\x90\\xd7\\x95': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3ad7fe48>,
 '3501': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3aa1fbe0>,
 '7214': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3a798cf8>,
 '87195': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x1ca3aab47b8>,
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet from the `.txt` file so we can debug it?

Comment: Yes, just opened it and see that already the .txt file is in this format:b''
b'\xd7\xa7\xd7\x90&\xd7\xa0\xd7\xa6\xd7\x9c\xd7\xa8\xd7\x99\xd7\xaa \xd7\x92\xd7\xa8\xd7\x9e\xd7\xa0\xd7\x99\xd7\x94 \xd7\x90\xd7\xa0\xd7\x92\xd7\x9c\xd7\x94 \xd7\x9e\xd7\xa8\xd7\xa7\xd7\x9c \xd7\x90\xd7\x9e\xd7\xa8 \xd7\x90\xd7\xaa\xd7\x9e\xd7\xa9\xd7\x95\xd7\xaa \xd7\x9e\xd7\xa4\xd7\x9c\xd7\x92\xd7\x94 \xd7\xa9\xd7\x99&\xd7\x9c\xd7\x98\xd7\x95\xd7\x9f \xd7\x93\xd7\xa6\xd7\x9e\xd7\x91\xd7\xa8'

Comment: this is the way I created the txt file from the list of sentences: with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in new_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item.encode('utf8'))

Comment: Please add this to your question. Not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> This is the way I created the txt file from the list of sentences:
>
> ```
> with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
>     for item in new_list: 
>         f.write("%s\n" % item.encode('utf8'))
> ```

This doesn't work, interpolating bytes (the result of `str.encode`) into a string implicitly calls `str` on the `bytes`, resulting in

```
"b'mystring'\n"
```

Note the "b" *inside* the quotation marks - what's being written to the file is a string, not the encoded bytes.

The right ways to do this are either to declare the desired encoding when opening the file, and write *text*:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for item in new_list:
        f.write('%s\n' % item)  # assuming item is already a str
```

or to open the file in binary mode, and write *bytes*:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for item in new_list:
        f.write(('%s\n' % item).encode('utf-8'))  # make the string, _then_ encode
```

If you execute Python with the [-b](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-b) flag, a warning will be emitted the first time you call `str` on a `bytes` instance; if you use the -bb flag, an exception will be raised.